# What is Model in MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture

I have some confusion regarding the implementation of model in MVVM, which one of the below 2 points make most sense?

- Should we consider Model as the Repository and have reference of repository in ViewModel.
- There should be separate model class which interacts with repository and ViewModel have reference of that model class.

Comment: A model is nothing but a class that represents your data. It tells you the architecture/blueprint of data that will flow from bottom to top and vice versa. A repository is not a model, it's the only job is to fetch data either locally or cloud-based.

Comment: So what pattern do you suggest to get data inside viewmodel? point 1 or 2?

Comment: I use point 2, the viewmodel sees the model and the model gets the data from repository, this way if you change the repository (for example getting the data from a json instead of a file) and the model and viewmodel should not require any change as the business logic has not changed

Comment: All the MV* patterns (MVC, MVP, MVVM) describe only how to separate the UI. But the UI is only one part of an application. You cannot expect to find the whole application concept described by the MV* pattern.

Comment: So when they say model they are actually saying that everything in your application other than view? @SirRufo

Comment: No - when you talk about the wheels of your car, did you care about the engine? But you need an engine for the car - but when talking about the wheels it does not matter

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up agreeing with @SirRufo and now implementing clean architecture to get better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Model holds the business logic, this includes your Domain and Data Layer. Repository is just a part of Model.